# How to collaborate on a Microsoft Bot Framework project?

Tags: git, heroku, botframework, collaboration

I have built a bot with Microsoft Bot Framework.

Currently, my architecture is:

- Heroku production bot in continuous deployment with 'master' Github branch
- Heroku development bot in continous deployment with 'dev' Github branch

I'd like to collaborate with my new team on the bot, but we don't want to commit everytime we do any change in the code.

Problem is that MBF only has one endpoint ('https://yyy.herokuapps.com' for example) it starts on.
I worked with an ngrok server before when I was alone to test locally.

Everyone its own local testing bot seems a bit overkill for me.

How should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [deployment pipeline](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines) for your product and link the production step to your production branch, and the dev step to your dev branch. You'll need more than one dyno for this, so it may charge you for usage, but you should be able to hit both the dev environment and the production environments separately. [source: Heroku Docs -> Accessing Pipelines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines#accessing-pipelines)

Comment: I thought about this solution, but it doesn't solve the endpoint problem: bot can have only one endpoint, it's not like a classical project where you can easy test locallly. To work with a team on the bot, we can only work on the endpoint provided (see here in MBF: [link](https://puu.sh/wqElU/211580eea7.png), and here in Facebook dev center: [link](https://puu.sh/wqEuJ/359138080e.png).
I wonder how people do to work together on chatbots using officials channels like Facebook, Slack...